# How do I zoom in one window in Unity

Tags: compiz, window, zooming

I'm trying to zoom in (or scale up) one window on the Macbook Pro with HiDPI/retina screen in Unity on 12.04. This is useful for some applications that doesn't allow the font size etc. to be changed. It would also be useful to e.g. scale up Virtualbox on hi-res screens.

The compiz zoom plugin zooms the entire desktop, so that's not what I need. The shelf plugin does what I want, but only scales windows down.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's another plug-in if you open the compiz configuration manager (ccsm) called "Enhanced zoom Desktop". There you can define the key binding for the zoom, and keys to zoom only an area or a window.

In case you don't have that option, or even the ccsm, you will have to install the packages that includes the extra plug ins. I do it trough synaptic in every new Ubuntu installation. Just search "compiz" and install all the available packages (except the KDE related ones).

Wish it helps, good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I installed that and it works OK. It seems like it is impossible to zoom in on only one window due to problems with input redirection in the X server.

Answer (score 0):

The "Freely Transformable Windows" plugin will make windows bigger, as well as smaller, and is installed as part of the `compiz-plugins` package.

However, there's an important caveat: input doesn't work correctly, and can't be made to do so. X.org doesn't support input redirection (as hengestone points out), so the default in the Freely Transformable Windows plugin is to disable input. If you enable input, you'll find that clicks don't go where you'd expect - they go to where they would have gone, if the window hadn't been scaled up.