# Zoom a Single Window

Tags: display-resolution, zooming

I have a 4 k display which is great. I can fit a lot of stuff in there and most applications have a big enough font which can be easily read even in a quarter of the intended area (when designed for full hd). However, there are some applications with a too small font size which makes it hard to read what they say.

Finding options to zoom the entire desktop ([on demand](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185533/how-do-i-zoom-in-one-window-in-unity)) isn't hard, but I only want to zoom specific windows. It this possible, too?

I'm using Ubuntu 15.04 with Unity.

Comment: @MartyFried Yes, I'm using Compiz.

Comment: Sorry, I started to write a comment, but didn't mean to enter it, but when I switched to Compiz Configuration tool, it entered the partial comment.  I thought there was a plugin that did this, but found it only zooms out, but not in (shelf).  And it will maximize certain windows, but not zoom in.  The zoom in plugin zooms entire desktop, although it has an option to zoom the focused window to fill the screen, an could be a work around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a script called `run_scaled` which uses [xpra](http://xpra.org/) to run a single application in a scaled environment:

https://github.com/kaueraal/run_scaled